# CXF JSON Schema Validation

Tags: json, web-services, cxf

I am writing RESTFul webservices which support both XML and JSON format. I need to add schema validation in the webservices. My beans are auto generated using JAX-B. As suggested at CXF's site at [Schema validation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+Data+Bindings#JAX-RSDataBindings-Schemavalidation), I am using `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` as JSON provider and `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider` as JAX-B provider. The request and response is working fine but now I want to add schema validation.

The sample code at above CXF link is not working for me for JSON schema validation (its working for XML schema validation). They shown it for `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider` (under 'Schema Validation' section) which doesn't work for me as my beans are JAX-B generated, so I am using `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`.

Is there any solution for this problem? Could somebody please suggest some approach that I can try?

Below is the XML configuration:

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>      

<bean id="schemaHolder" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.schemas.SchemaHandler">
    <property name="schemas" ref="theSchemas"/>
</bean>

<util:list id="theSchemas">
  <value>classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/po.xsd</value>
</util:list>

<!-- Person REST Service Configurations -->
<bean id="personRESTServiceImpl" class="com.abc.webservices.service.rest.PersonRESTService" />
<jaxrs:server id="personRESTService" address="/person-rest-service">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="personRESTServiceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
        <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: There is one more configuration which is not getting copied. Its:   <bean id="jaxbProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider" >
        <property name="schemaHandler" ref="schemaHolder"/>
    </bean>

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is wrong, in web application classpath is WEB-INF/classes

Hence you can use following configuration

```
<jaxrs:schemaLocations>
                <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:po.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
</jaxrs:schemaLocations>
```

if you have xsd directory in classes directory then `classpath:xsd/po.xsd`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Karthik. I tried the way you suggested and its working for XML format only and not for JSON format. Its NOT checking for mandatory field( which are marked as @XmlElement(required = true)). Also it returned me 500 Internal Server Error if I send any invalid field (without returning the reason, I can see it failed in validation in log files) while I was expecting 400 with validation reason.